# Почему форма заказа не срабатывает 2 раз?

Tags: jquery, ajax, битрикс

**Здравствуйте, не могу понять причину, почему форма быстрой покупки не срабатывает, с другим товаром**

Выбрав 1 товар который в наличии > нажимаю кнопку быстрая покупка > форма срабатывает (всё ок) > далее я закрываю эту форму (крестиком) > перехожу к товару 2 который в наличии (переходы происходят по системе AJAX) > нажимаю кнопку быстрая покупка > ОШИБКА (Форма не вызывается)

**Но если обновить страницу, то форма снова начинает работать**

Помогите решить задачу...
Сайт работает на 1C-Bitrix, автокэш отключен, композит отключен, каталог работает по принципу AJAX, компонент вызова формы быстрой покупки тоже AJAX

[Сайт для тестирования](https://tehvideoservis.ru/catalog/)

Comment: Немного не понятен вопрос. Можно код

Comment: И сообщение ошибки тоже бы не помешало бы

Comment: @Руслан, под ошибкой я подразумеваю то что форма не работает так как должна..Могу показать код но я думаю что его нужно показывать очень много...

Comment: @Руслан, попробуй сам испытать сайт по схеме которую я описал... Я заметил после перехода к другому товару, форма быстрой покупки висит в DOM с данными от первого товара, и как то нужно сделать чтобы она обнавлялась

Comment: Если Вы подразумеваете очистить форму, то это делается примерно так $("#idForm")[0].reset();

Comment: @Руслан, я сделал после закрытия формы $("#idForm").remove()
но это не помогло, форма удаляется со страницы, но после не добавляется, я не могу понять причину.... Может проблема в кнопке и её нужно как то обновить, или что то ещё..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74733/discussion-between---and-).

Comment: Позже сейчас я занят